# Verifying inequality with a specific set of parameter restrictions

Tags: inequalities

I would like to have Mathematica check an inequality over a set of parameter restrictions. More in detail, given a function $f(x;a,b)$, where $a$, and $b$ are parameters, I would like to verify that 
$$f(x;a,b) \leq f(1;a,b)$$ subject to a set of constraints on $x$, and $a$, $b$.

Here is an example of the problem I am working with. Define $$f(x;a,b)= x \ln\left(1 + \frac{(1 + x/2)^2}{a b}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{a b - 1 + (x/2)^2}{a b}\right).$$ The corresponding Mathematica code is:

`Example[a_, b_, x_] := 
  x Log[1 + (1 + x/2)^2/(a b)] + Log[(a b - 1 + (x/2)^2)/(a b)];`

I impose $a b > 1$ for $f(\cdot)$ to be well defined, and if I plot it in Mathematica with a `Manipulate` command, I can see that it is maximal at $x = 1$:

`Manipulate[If[a < 1/b, a = 1/b + 0.001]; 
 Plot[{Example[a, b, 1], Example[a, b, x]}, {x, 0, 1}], {a, .01, 
  5}, {b, .01, 5}]`

[image]

Keeping in mind that this is a simple example of a more complicated problem (the actual function has 4 parameters, and what I call $x$ in my example is itself a parametric function), is there a way to have Mathematica check that what the plot displays is true? I have first tried `Reduce`:

`Reduce[Example[a, b, x] < Example[a, b, 1] && 0 < x <= 1 && a b > 1 &&
    b > 0, x] // Quiet`

with the result that Mathematica just outputs my definition:

`Reduce[x Log[1 + (1 + x/2)^2/(a b)] + Log[(-1 + a b + x^2/4)/(a b)] < 
   Log[1 + 9/(4 a b)] + Log[(-(3/4) + a b)/(a b)] && 0 < x <= 1 && 
  a b > 1 && b > 0, x]`

Alternatively, I have tried `NMaximize`, to check whether there could be solutions $x<1$:

`NMaximize[{Example[a, b, x], 0 < x <= 1, a b > 1, b > 0}, x] // Quiet`

but again (and even with this simple function), Mathematica simply returns my definition:

`NMaximize[{x Log[1 + (1 + x/2)^2/(a b)] + 
   Log[(-1 + a b + x^2/4)/(a b)], 0 < x <= 1, a b > 1, b > 0}, x]`

My question is: does this depend on the fact that the function involves logs? If so, is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here its considered helpful and polite show you own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I did not mean to be impolite. It's just that the actual function I work with is rather complicated, and pasting it would require a much longer post. I will think of a simplifying example and get back to this.